# How to show that an item in a form is dependent on the previous item

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

So I am designing a system where you can group different items together. A VNET is a group of edge devices, and in order to get the "TNI/Addr", you need to first select the VNET. I added some lines to separate the disabled item from the rest of this form, but I feel like there is still no visual cue that shows the dependency between the two items. Here is a screenshot/wireframe:

[image]

Is there a clearer way to show  that the TNI is dependent/enabled once you select a VNET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article talks about dependent form fields: https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2007/02/selection-dependent-inputs.php

I think this option works best since it allows you to have as many options in the dropdown as possible, and it simply adds a bounding box without any extra instructions. The UI itself tells the user the relationship between the fields.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **helper text pattern** in the form to tell them directly.

##### Option 1: Helper text only

[image]
You are already using helper text for the **MAC Address** input, so you can have the text below telling them specifically what they need to do. This might be enough to give clarity.

##### Option 2: Group together with a subhead + helper text

To be more clear cut, you can group them together into a small subsection. I've added a subheader to give them context and separation from the other non-dependent inputs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide TNI/Addr on the form by default, and show it only when the user selects a VNET.